# maven, ant plugin, antrun:run

Tags: maven-2, ant, maven-plugin

When executing 'mvn antrun:run' my tasks are not run.. I have an echo task, but no output is shown.. When running the phases that the tasks are bound to, they do get executed..

How do I specifically execute the tasks from the commandline?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming something like this is added to your pom.xml

```
<build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase><!--Change this to control when it runs -->
              <configuration>
                <tasks>
            <echo  message="Hello, maven"/>
                </tasks>
              </configuration>
              <goals>
                <goal>run</goal><!-- this is to call antrun:run -->
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
```

Executing `mvn package` will result in the following on your console

```
[INFO] [antrun:run {execution: default}]
[INFO] Executing tasks
     [echo] Hello, maven
[INFO] Executed tasks
```

You can change the `phase` to have your ant script run at whatever point you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm using this specific ant task to deploy an axis webservice ( with a program called AdminClient). I can only deploy it after my container ( in this case jetty:run ) has started.. So which phase would be relevant?

Comment: Jetty:run would likely be running at pre-integration-test. I would change the phase to post-integration-test. The run "mvn verify" to run both the jetty and ant tasks.